# I need help to make a correction

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

The shape of the diagram I want to draw in the following picture:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
                 &   &               1   \\
                 &  1^{\ast} \arrow[dash, dashed,ldd]  & \\
                 & \quad \quad ~~~~~~ r  ~~~~~~\arrow[dash, dashed,ruu] & \\
                 s^{\ast}  &  &
    \end{tikzcd},
    \begin{tikzcd}
    &\begin{array}{rlc} ~1^{\ast}~\\ ~~~1\end{array}\arrow[dash, dashed,dr] \arrow[dash, dashed, dl]& \\
     s^{\ast} &  & r
    \end{tikzcd},
    \begin{tikzcd} ~1^{\ast} \arrow[dash,dashed,dr] && 1 \arrow[dash,dashed,dl] \\
                 & \begin{array}{rlc} s^{\ast}~~~\\ ~r~\end{array} & 
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: What does "draw with my hands" mean? What is the problem with your source code?

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You mention 3 diagrams, but your code contains 4 ??

Comment: The what-you-see-is-what-you-get online [`tikzcd` editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) may help you get the right code of your desired diagrams.

Comment: I tried tikzcd editor, but it wasn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The 1*r, 1*1, s*r in your hand made diagrams correspond to indices, or to  side by side elements?

Comment: s^{\ast}, 1^{\ast}, r and 1 be side by side elements with different segments. Similar to the vertex of Aulander-Reiten quiver.

Answer (score 2):

With `[...]` after `&` or `\\` you can control the distance between columns or rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & &[-3.5em] & 1 \\
    & 1^{\ast}\ar[dash, dashed, ldd]\\[-4.5ex]
    & & r\ar[dash, dashed, ruu]\\
    s^{\ast}\\
\end{tikzcd},
\begin{tikzcd}
    & 1^{\ast}\ar[dash, dashed, ldd] &[-3.5em]\\[-4.5ex]
    & & 1\ar[dash, dashed, rd]\\
    s^{\ast} & & & r\\
\end{tikzcd},
\begin{tikzcd}
1^{\ast}\ar[dash, dashed, rd]& &[-3.5em] & 1\\
&s^{\ast}\\[-4.5ex]
&&r\ar[dash, dashed, uur]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]